# Timeout, when requesting "special" web site

Tags: c#, http, https, html-agility-pack, anglesharp

I wanted to request https://www.gesetze-im-internet.de/bgb/__1.html, but then I get a timeout, it seems that the web site does not want to be read by a program.

I was trying to change the userAgent and using a different library(anglesharp), but nothing worked:

```
 var web = new HtmlWeb();
 web.UserAgent = @"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.1; en-US; rv:1.9.1.5) Gecko/20091102 Firefox/3.5.5";
 var doc = web.Load("https://www.gesetze-im-internet.de/bgb/__1.html");
```

How can I solve this ?

Comment: 'seems that the web site does not want to be read by a program'. 'How can I solve this ?' Ask them, if you get allowance. If not, dont do it.

Comment: I've just tried loading that URL with Fiddler, and it loads OK.  Are you sure there isn't some VPN or Proxy blocking your connection?

Comment: @Neil Thanks, you were right. I was trying it on different Computer and it worked. But actualy I got no clue where to start, not at all because it only does not work with specific website. But when I request google(https) it works. You got any ideas ?